# Apache POI-HSSF distorts image size when adding picture into Excel cell

Tags: java, image, excel, apache-poi, hssf

I am adding a picture into a cell using Apache POI-HSSF. The image is 120x100 but no matter what I do and how I resize it, the Excel spreadsheet always shows it spanning multiple rows and distorts it to a much bigger height than width.

How do I keep the original size?

My code:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(getImageURL());
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
int pictureIdx = wb.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);
is.close();

//add a picture shape
CreationHelper helper = wb.getCreationHelper();
ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
// Create the drawing patriarch.  This is the top level container for all shapes.
Drawing drawing = sheet1.createDrawingPatriarch();
//set top-left corner of the picture,
//subsequent call of Picture#resize() will operate relative to it

anchor.setAnchorType(0);
anchor.setCol1(1);
anchor.setRow1(1);

Picture pict = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);

//auto-size picture relative to its top-left corner
pict.resize();
```

I've tried all dx/dy coordinates and Col/Row. The position doesn't matter, the problem it stretches the image horizontally.

Comment: I've discovered this happens when I set the Row's Height using row.setHeight(). If I don't do this, the image is fine. No matter how large I make the height, the image is still stretched vertically.

Answer (score 6):

I had been facing the similar issue where the image I added was getting distorted. I tried pict.resize() and sheet.autoSizeColumn() but it didn't work. Finally I found the below URL:-
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/examples/ss/AddDimensionedImage.java

I added the above class into my code and used it's method to add the image into excel. I was able to add the image with little distortion. Hope this helps to you also. I wrote below code:-

```
BufferedImage imageIO = ImageIO.read(new URL(image));
int height= imageIO.getHeight();
int width=imageIO.getWidth();
int relativeHeight=(int)(((double)height/width)*28.5);
new AddDimensionedImage().addImageToSheet(2,  sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()-1 , sheet, sheet.createDrawingPatriarch(),new URL(image), 30, relativeHeight, AddDimensionedImage.EXPAND_ROW);
```

Comment: The AddDimensionedImage.java seems to have moved. New URL: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/examples/ss/AddDimensionedImage.java

Answer (score 3):

As far as i understood from documentation of Apache POI, it is because of `pict.resize();`
,as it says [here](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Picture.html#resize%28%29) that if the default font size for the workbook was changed, the picture might get stretched vertically or horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

I've the same problem and my solution was copy this class in my project 
[AddDimensionedImage](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/ss/examples/AddDimensionedImage.java) and then used this method.

```
protected void addImageInCell(Sheet sheet, URL url, Drawing<?> drawing, int colNumber, int rowNumber) {
    BufferedImage imageIO = ImageIO.read(url);
    int height = imageIO.getHeight();
    int width = imageIO.getWidth();
    int relativeHeight = (int) (((double) height / width) * 28.5);
    new AddDimensionedImage().addImageToSheet(colNumber, rowNumber, sheet, drawing, url, 30, relativeHeight,
            AddDimensionedImage.EXPAND_ROW_AND_COLUMN);

}
```

you can call this method with follow line:

```
URL url = new URL("https://blog.expedia.mx/por-que-los-viajeros-internacionales-visitan-mexico/");
addImageInCell(sheet, url, sheet.createDrawingPatriarch(), 0, 0);
```

Comment: The AddDimensionedImage.java seems to have moved. New URL: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/examples/ss/AddDimensionedImage.java

Answer (score 0):

I created another empty image with the width taken from `sheet.getColumnWidthInPixels`, draw the necessary image over it and used `AddDimensionedImage.EXPAND_ROW_AND_COLUMN` to fit it exactly into the cell:

```
    HSSFRow imageRow = sheet.createRow(row);

    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(Paths.get(pathToImage).toUri().toURL());

    AddDimensionedImage addImage = new AddDimensionedImage();
    float columnWidth = sheet.getColumnWidthInPixels(0);

    BufferedImage off_Image = new BufferedImage((int) columnWidth, actualImageHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = off_Image.createGraphics();
    g2.setColor(new Color(192,192,192));
    g2.fillRect(0, 0, off_Image.getWidth(), off_Image.getHeight());
    g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    g2.dispose();

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(off_Image, "jpg", baos);
    byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();

    double reqImageWidthMM = ((double) off_Image.getWidth()) / ConvertImageUnits.PIXELS_PER_MILLIMETRES;
    double reqImageHeightMM = ((double) off_Image.getHeight()) / ConvertImageUnits.PIXELS_PER_MILLIMETRES;

    addImage.addImageToSheet("A1", sheet, bytes, reqImageWidthMM, reqImageHeightMM, AddDimensionedImage.EXPAND_ROW_AND_COLUMN);
```

I had to copy [AddDimensionedImage.java](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/ss/examples/AddDimensionedImage.java) to my classpath and overload `addImageToSheet` to accept byte array.

Before that I tried other options mentioned here but it didn't help. Hope my answer will be useful to someone.

Comment: The AddDimensionedImage.java seems to have moved. New URL: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/examples/ss/AddDimensionedImage.java